# How can I change top bar menu options?

Tags: gnome, menu, top-bar

How can I change the top menu options for one or all of the apps?

[image]

Comment: This is controlled by the application itself so, if you would like to modify what goes in the menus, you'll need to edit the source code for that specific application 

Comment: @Matigo I always see the Quit option... it doesn't matter what app I'm in. Is this written for each application or is it in GNOME itself? If it is from GNOME, I want to add something like this to menu so that it can be seen in all applications

Comment: This is in the application itself. A lot of development tools will pre-populate the Quit function when a menu is defined. If the development team elects to remove the option, they can. Most keep it in place, though, as there are many people who are more comfortable with the application than pressing [Alt]+[F4] or clicking on a tiny X in a corner.